# Assign number of rows deleted to a variable in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to get the number of rows deleted from a table and use it in my procedure. Could you please let me know how to get the number of deleted into a variable in snowflake.

Below is the sample block that am trying to execute. Not sure how to assign TABLE(rs) to a variable.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  rs RESULTSET;
  cnt INTEGER;
  query VARCHAR DEFAULT 'DELETE FROM leased_bicycles where bicycle_ID in ( 105, 106)';
BEGIN
  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  //cnt := TABLE(rs);
  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
$$;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [Returning a RESULTSET as a Table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets#returning-a-resultset-as-a-table)
>
> If you want to return the results that the RESULTSET points to, pass the RESULTSET to TABLE().
>
> > **Currently, the TABLE(resultset_name) syntax is supported only in the RETURN statement.**

Unfortunately it is not possible to simply use:

```
DECLARE
  rs RESULTSET;
  cnt INTEGER;
  query VARCHAR DEFAULT 'DELETE FROM leased_bicycles where bicycle_ID in ( 105, 106)';
BEGIN
  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);

  SELECT * INTO :cnt FROM TABLE(rs);  -- this will not work

  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

---

It is still possible to access this info from RESULTSET though in a "hacky" way(not recommended).

Approach: Temporary procedure inside Snowflake Scripting block and usage of [CALL sp INTO variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75151945/5070879)

The temporary stored procedure must return single row and column.

```
DECLARE
    cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY PROCEDURE temp_proc()
    RETURNS TABLE()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    DECLARE
      rs RESULTSET;
      query VARCHAR DEFAULT 'DELETE FROM leased_bicycles where bicycle_ID in (105, 106)';
    BEGIN
      rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
    
      RETURN TABLE(rs);
    END;

    CALL temp_proc() INTO cnt;

    RETURN cnt;
END;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE leased_bicycles(bicycle_id INT)
AS
SELECT 105 UNION ALL SELECT 106 UNION ALL SELECT 107;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate for the help. Solution you have provided works

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `SQLROWCOUNT` for this and not result set.

Here is an example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS WHERE RIDE_ID='FE19F6764C854519';
  SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS;
  IF (SQLFOUND = true) THEN
    RETURN SQLROWCOUNT;
  ELSEIF (SQLNOTFOUND = true) THEN
    RETURN 'No rows deleted.';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'SQLFOUND and SQLNOTFOUND are not true.';
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

The above code gives me back:

[image]

You can read more about determining the number of rows affected by DML commands on our docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/dml-status).